# Edge dev tools for VS Code gives "ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT" error during authentication, possibly from the "file:///" url scheme - is there a workaround?

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-code, microsoft-edge

I am currently using the latest stable VS Code version on Windows 10 (ver 20H2, build 19042.1826) with the [Edge Dev Tools VS Code extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/visual-studio-code/microsoft-edge-devtools-extension). The application I'm currently developing is just a static site using Vue.js, not using a Node.js server to run and debug. The Edge tools work great, right out of the box. I started up the app by opening the root "index.html" file, and clicked "Run and Debug" per the documentation.

[image: App start up]

The app starts up, I can hit breakpoints, etc. all good. However, this app uses a 3rd party service to authenticate and authorize users (from ArcGIS Online) and it seems the "file:///C:/path/to/root/index.html" url is not allowed to be redirected back to from the authentication service page.

[image: ERR_UNSAFE_REDIRECT in Edge]

My Google-fu is failing me here and I can't seem to figure out how this would work. Has anyone experienced such an issue before? Is it possible to use a "http://localhost" url on some port here instead?

The authentication service disallows setting a redirect url which has a "file:///" scheme.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To resolve this issue, I followed the guidance in [yu-zhou](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11490347/yu-zhou)'s comments above. My solution was to use the [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) VS Code extension to host and run the app locally. I set the "NoBrowser" setting in Live Server to "true" so that a new browser instance would **not** be launched on Live Server startup. I then configured launch.json as follows:

```js
{
    "name": "Edge: Debug app",
    "request": "launch",
    "type": "msedge",
    "url": "http://localhost:5500/my-app/index.html",
    "runtimeArgs": ["--disable-web-security"],
    "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**", "**/*.com*/**"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to avoid exposing users to open redirector attacks, developers must register one or more redirect URLs for the application. The authorization server must never redirect to any other location. You can try adding a redirect URI according to [this doc](https://developers.arcgis.com/documentation/mapping-apis-and-services/security/tutorials/add-redirect-uri/).

IMO, `file:///` scheme may not work, so I suggest you use a `http://localhost` url since only http and https are mentioned in the doc.

Comment: Correct, arcgis.com does not allow a redirect url which contains a "file:///" scheme. Using a "localhost:port" would be the ideal configuration, however I did not see this mentioned anywhere in the VS Code Edge Dev Tools docs. Posting here in hopes someone has found if/how this can be done with this extension.

Comment: VS Code Edge Dev Tools is used for debugging with no ability to run any file on localhost. So you need to run your local file on localhost first. After you have set up your localhost, you need to configure `launch.json` file. You can find it in Run and Debug --> Dropdown menu --> Add Config (project name) --> Web App (Edge or Chrome). Here's a `launch.json` configuration sample for you: https://i.stack.imgur.com/dlDI0.png

Comment: Thank you, Yu Zhou - the [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer) VS Code extension and a configuration similar to the one in your screen shot has resolved my issue. I am able to start up the app, hit breakpoints, use the Edge dev tools within VS Code, and no issue on the SSO redirect!